# Cannot get response from App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync call using MSAL

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, adfs, azure-ad-msal

I've been using the example project at [active-directory-xamarin-native-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2) to get my Xamarin (Android and iOS) app to authenticate to work's AD.

I registered my app on-line in Azure (apps.dev.microsoft.com) and plugged the application ID into the sample app and it worked, I hit my ID and it authenticated me using work's login page (shows the login.microsoftonline.com page) then returned a valid token to the calling example code.

However, when I followed the example through and implemented it in my own code, everything was fine up to the point that I hit the...

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes, App.UiParent);
```

...in the Login button event handler part of the code (line 44, MainPage.xaml.cs if anyone has the project locally).

When I hit the login button it correctly takes me to the MS/work login page but when I select my ID on the page it just does nothing, doesn't come back to the handler, just sits there until I hit Back and then it comes back to the handler, but in an unauthenticated state.

So...

- I've checked the android manifest - same.
- I've checked the app id in all parts of the code where it's used, same.
- Called the same events in the same (equivalent) places - same.
- I'm using the same main form and main activity types.

Has anyone else used this example and successfully integrated MSAL into their application and found a nasty little gotcha lurking in there?!? I've been banging my head against this one for a day and a half.

I appreciate this is a hard one to diagnose without me posting rather too much code, I'm just hoping someone else has had the same experience and found the problem (and is willing to share!!).

EDIT: So I noticed that the original sample project uses a Portable shared code project, whereas mine uses a shared.  Created a shared project version of the sample project - doesn't work.

Tried creating a Portable based version of my app, stripping it back to the bare bones, couldn't get it to work so I'm going to drop this for now and find an alternative method.  Maybe I'll come back to this once it's out of pre-release.

Comment: this seems like a deadlock? are you using await everywhere? (no .Result calls from the UI thread). Do you want to try with a ConfigureAwait(false)  ?

Comment: @Jean-MarcPrieur Sadly I can't see any call which doesn't have an await, but thanks for the suggestion.  I'll look into the ConfigureAwait(false).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've been preparing xamarin.android B2C prototype according to [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2) sample (same as yours).

In one moment I was in similar situation like you. I was successfully redirected to AAD web page and when I pressed "Sign in" button the thread in my app never continued.

The nasty little gotcha lurking in there was:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

in MainActivity.cs in android project which I overlooked.

Comment: Unfortunately not the case for me, wish it had been that simple, but I'd meticulously copied each and every method and class to the original project.  That one was there but only received an event if I pressed Back out of the AAD screen and the result would be "User cancelled" or similar

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I stuffed up the first time when I made the Shared version of the demo app (bad references it appears).

Tried again today and it works, so I painstakingly transferred each and every component from my original app to the new one, testing after each piece was moved until I eventually (took an entire day!) had a working version of my app with the login mechanism working.

When I get some time, I'm going to compare the two versions and see if I can find the critical difference between them and fix the original, so I can understand what went wrong.